# Getting undefined on this function call

Tags: javascript

I think the fact that it takes time to write to the database is making this function undefined. Am I right? If so, how do programmers avoid a million nested functions in the callbacks of database calls?

```
function createStripeCustomer(email) {
            stripe.customers.create({
                    email: email
                },
                function (err, customer) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('The stripe error is ', err);
                    }
                    console.log('The created customer id is ', customer.id); // This works

                    return customer.id;   // we know customer.id works because it shows up in console 
                }
            );
}
```

For some reason, this gives undefined:

```
var getCustomerId = createStripeCustomer(req.body.email);
console.log ('This should say the id but it says undefined: ', getCustomerId);
```

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: Thanks Slaks! Where would I put .then in my example? After createStripeCustomer(req.body.email)?

Comment: Also, I'm very impressed with you being a stack overflow celebrity :) Thank you for your genius!

Comment: To use `.then()`, you must make your function return a promise, which the API you're using may or may not return already.  If it doesn't, see http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-05/introducing-promises/#creating-promises